# JSON parsing and stringify

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, stringify

I am currently working on a Javascript project where I have to parse tons of data. The project requires that I parse some JSON data and bring specific data into another array. Right now, I am using the JSON.stringify method and I can console.log all of the data that I need. The data looks something like this:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        -85.3865810000125,
                        33.90171899971196
                    ],
                    [
                        -85.38659500025622,
                        33.9017919996593
                    ],
```

yes, this is not all that data-it is about 1200 pages long! I only pasted in the top segment of it. All I really need is how to get to the coordinates aspect of it and into an array. So what I am currently doing is this:

```
var work = JSON.stringify(response, null, 4)
console.log(work);
```

Which gives me the above response. However, I am not that familiar with JSON.stringify so if I do:

```
console.log(work.type);
```

Attempting to see what the value is for type, I get a response of undefined. Now if I try doing this:

```
var work = JSON.parse(response)
console.log(work);
```

I get a response of:  VM296:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Thus, I cannot get the data parsed which I want to get to which will be the coordinates data. Any help with using stringify would great help me. I have read a lot about how it turns the data into a string but have not really seen a lot about how to parse it. Do I have to use parse? Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is not a valid json

Comment: You are not finishing the JSON, and as @NiharSarkar said, it is also not valid.

Comment: just do `response.type` to get the `type` property. no need to stringify it, it is already a javascript object.

Comment: The JSON is not finished because it is 1200 pages long! So i don't want to paste that in here-sorry for the confusion!

Comment: what do you get when you console.log(response)?  Is it an object?  Is it valid json?  Is it a puppy?

Comment: It doesn’t look like the JSON that is _actually_ used is invalid. It’s just incompletely copy-pasted in this question (_“tons of data”_). @Daniel_L is right, `response` is already an object, so just take `response.type`. You only need to _parse_ if it’s a JSON string and you need a property of that, and you only need to _stringify_ if you need to convert an object to a string. You need neither, in this case.

Comment: By the way, “Unexpected token `o`” means that the object got converted to the string `"[object Object]"`, most likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont' have to use `stringify` or `parse` for this. The response object you are receiving is already a javascript object so you can reference its properties normally

`response.type; // => "FeatureCollection"`

If you try and `stringify` the response it will lose its `type` property, for instance:

`typeof "some string".someProperty; // => undefined`

Comment: Yup! I tried response.type and got exactly what you said! Thank you for the help and the explanation! Time to dig in and find what I need!